# Why is 0xF used for bitwise operations involving conversions from BCD values to integers?

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators, bcd

This may be a really dumb question, but why is 0xF used in the bitwise operations when converting from a BCD values to an integer. I understand that 0xF represents something like 0x15, which is equal to 00010101 in binary.
However, why is this particular value used in the bitwise operation in the above program? What is the significance of this value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N_BCD_DIGITS 8

uint32_t packed_bcd(uint32_t packed_bcd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        long l = strtol(argv[arg], NULL, 0);
        assert(l >= 0 && l <= UINT32_MAX);
        uint32_t packed_bcd_value = l;

        printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)packed_bcd(packed_bcd_value));
    }

    return 0;
}

// given a packed BCD encoded value between 0 .. 99999999
// return the corresponding integer

uint32_t packed_bcd(uint32_t packed_bcd_value) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = N_BCD_DIGITS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int decimal_digit = (packed_bcd_value >> (4 * i)) & 0xF;
        assert(decimal_digit < 10);
        result = result * 10 + decimal_digit;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `0xF` does not equal `0x15`. It equals `15 (base 10)`...

Comment: `0xF` *hexadecimal* is `15` *decimal*, both are `00001111` in *binary*.

Comment: @Fe2O3: not really, all you need to do is use the hexadecimal format: with a command line argument of `0x123`, the program will output `123`.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks... My bad... Misread '0' as '10'... Have deleted the comment...

Comment: @Juan Montoya `int result = 0;` better as `uint32_t result = 0;` for correct functionality.

Comment: In BCD each decimal digit is stored in a nibble. `0xF` is the bitmask to mask out a nibble. And that's about it, it's not more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(packed_bcd_value >> (4 * i)) & 0xF` extracts the i-th digit (numbered 0 to 7) from the BCD encoded value: the value `packed_bcd_value` is shifted right by `4 * i` bits, shifting out the bits from the digits with a lower number bits, and then the low 4 bits are extracted by masking off the other bits with a mask of `0b1111`, ie: all 4 low bits set. `0xF` is the hex representation for this number `15`. As of C23, you could use `0b1111`, but not all current compilers support this syntax.

You can test your program by giving command line arguments starting with `0x` as `strtol()` with a base of `0` will convert these as hexadecimal:

```
sh$ ./myprogram 0x123 291 100
123
123
64
```

Answer (score 2):

One digit in the HEX number represents the nibble (4 bits).

> I understand that 0xF represents something like 0x15, which is equal
> to 00010101

No, `0xf` is `15` in **decimal** (without 0x) and `0b1111` in binary.

When you binary AND any value with 0xf (0b1111) the result will contain the value of the lower 4 **bits** of this number.